# Show: Let $G$ be an archimedean ordered group, and given $0 \neq g \in G$, $h \in G$, $\exists n \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t $g^n \leq h < g^{n+1}$

Tags: group-theory

Here is my attempt: 
Suppose $h \geq 0$, then by Archimedean property of the ordering, $\exists n\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t  $h<g^{n+1}$. Hence consider the set $S$ of all $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $h<g^{k+1}$. By well ordering principle, $S$ has a minimum, call it $n+1$. Then $g^n<h<g^{n+1}$.

Now suppose $h<0$, then $h^{-1}>0$  and assume $g^{-1}>0$ so there is $n \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t $g^{-(n-1)} \leq h^{-1}<g^{-n}$ where $n$ is the smallest positive number satisfying this property. Then $g^{n+1} \geq h>g^n. But this is not what we want. Is this the right way to prove it?
[image]

Comment: It's absurd if $g<0$.

Comment: It was an exercise in the book.

Comment: what's in the book is correct, not what you wrote

Comment: Yes I know, that is why I want to know the right way to prove it. The book has no proof. Please help

Comment: But the claim in your title is false

Comment: but It's problem 2.3 in the book.

Comment: Try to read more carefully

Comment: Oh right sorry n is in $\mathbb{Z}$ Thank you for correcting me

Comment: Ok then for $g<0$ we can take $m<0$ and the set $\{-m|h<g^m\}$ has a minimal element,$n$, and that is the $n$ we should choose right?